# I am not able to solve this error in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your `SQL` syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your `MySQL` server version for the right syntax to use
>   near "*temp*" at line 1.

**Here's the code:**

```
public void DeleteColumn(string columnName)
{ 
    try
    {
        query.CommandText = "alter table publisher drop @col ";
        query.Prepare();
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", columnName);
        query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("column deleted successfully");
        transaction.Commit();
        Console.WriteLine("successfully committed to database");
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is the value i am passing in DeleteColumn:

```
DeleteColumn("temp");
```

There is no problem in connection and i have defined every needed values

Comment: have you debug code, if yes, please let me know which line of code throwing exception

Comment: Yes. query.ExecuteNonQuery(); is throwing the exception

Comment: query.CommandText = "alter table publisher DROP COLUMN @col ";  will resolve. change this line

Comment: I did that but i am still getting the same error

Comment: Please review this article. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9582c9/insert-update-delete-display-data-in-mysql-using-C-Sharp/. That's only I can suggest. Sorry

Comment: when i do this: query.CommandText = "alter table publisher drop temp "; it works @Pawan

Comment: Good. Now you have solution. enjoy..

Comment: but In my case i cannot use column name directly the value has to come from the method parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `column` to your drop statement

```
query.CommandText = "alter table publisher drop column @col ";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why your code is not working as you expected:**

You have error in the given query As per [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) syntax; the correct syntax for drop a column using alter table is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name"
DROP "column_name";
```

**Solution**

Change your CommandText like the following:

```
 query.CommandText = "alter table publisher DROP COLUMN @col ";
```

and the Parameters will be like :

```
 query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", columnName);//passed value to the function this must be the column name.
```

Hence your try block will be :

```
try
    {
        query.CommandText = "alter table publisher DROP COLUMN @col ";       
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", columnName);
        int result=query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
        if(result>0)
        Console.WriteLine("column deleted successfully");
        else
        Console.WriteLine("successfully committed to database");
    }
```

Comment: when i do this: query.CommandText = "alter table publisher drop temp "; it works

Answer (score 0):

Sql query syntax is wrong, use this.

```
query.CommandText = "alter table publisher DROP COLUMN @col ";
```